# CheckBox in FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I would like to present the user with **a list of items to choose from.** The items are sourced from a Redux state object. It is a list of the contacts on the device.

I used a **"FlatList"** from React-Native and a **"ListItem"** from React-Native-Elements. The ListItem has a **CheckBox.**

**For the user to check/uncheck an item in the list, he/she can click on the CheckBox or any part of the ListItem.**

**My 1st Attempt:** As you can see in the following code, I had to duplicate part of the code to achieve this. Is there a smarter way of doing this (to avoid code duplication)?

```
<FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    data={props.contactList}
    renderItem={_renderItem}
    ListEmptyComponent={<Text>There are no contacts to show.</Text>}
    refreshing={state.refreshing}
    onRefresh={_onRefresh}
/>

const _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
        <ListItem
            title={item.name}
            onPress={() => {
                // The following 2 statements are repeated (below)!!!
                _toggleCheck(index);
                props.acContactSelect(index);
            }}

            checkBox={{
                checked: _isItemChecked(index),
                checkedIcon: "check",
                onPress: () => {
                    // The following 2 statements are repeated (above)!!!
                    _toggleCheck(index);
                    props.acContactSelect(index);
                },
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

**My 2nd Attempt:** I tried using a function. I got the error message (Maximum update depth exceeded.)

```
<FlatList
.. {similar to the code above}
/>

const _renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
        <ListItem
        ..
            onPress={_onPress(index)}

            checkBox={{
                ..
                onPress: _onPress(index),
            }}
        />
    );
};

const _onPress = (index) => {
    _toggleCheck(index);
    props.acContactSelect(index);
};
```

Thanks for your effort and time to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please change this code**

```
<ListItem
        ..
            onPress={_onPress(index)}

            checkBox={{
                ..
                onPress: _onPress(index),
            }}
        />
```

**to**

```
<ListItem
        ..
            onPress={() =>_onPress(index)}

            checkBox={{
                ..
                onPress:() => _onPress(index),
            }}
        />
```

**onPress={_onPress(index)} will call function immediately**

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. I am still getting confused with the callback vs. call immediately. I need to read more on the subject.